# Duplicates allowed when constructing HashSet<T> with List<T> parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I am holding two lists in my program - one master list and another temporary list which is constantly being updated. Every so often, the temporary list flushes into the master list.

The master list is HashSet (for no-duplicates) and the temporary list is List (for indexing capability). I flush the latter into the former by calling

```
HashSet<T>.UnionWith(List<T>)
```

In my testing, I find that duplicates make their way into the list, yet I thought this wasn't possible in a HashSet. Can someone please confirm/correct this? I haven't been able to find it in MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> List (for indexing capability).

You'd want a dictionary for indexing.
On that note though, here's a very simple program that illustrates your problem:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int totalCats = 0;
        HashSet<Cat> allCats = new HashSet<Cat>();
        List<Cat> tempCats = new List<Cat>();

        //put 10 cats in
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tempCats.Add(new Cat(i));
            totalCats += 1;
        }

        //add the cats to the final hashset & empty the temp list
        allCats.UnionWith(tempCats);
        tempCats = new List<Cat>();

        //create 10 identical cats
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tempCats.Add(new Cat(i));
            totalCats += 1;
        }

        //join them again
        allCats.UnionWith(tempCats);
        //print the result
        Console.WriteLine("Total cats: " + totalCats);
        foreach (Cat curCat in allCats)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(curCat.CatNumber);
        }
    }
}

public class Cat
{
    public int CatNumber { get; set; }
    public Cat(int catNum)
    {
        CatNumber = catNum;
    }
}
```

Your problem is that you aren't overriding GetHashCode() and Equals(). You need to have both for the hash set to stay unique.

This will work, however the GetHashCode() function should be much more robust. I'd recommend reading up how .NET does it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int totalCats = 0;
        HashSet<Cat> allCats = new HashSet<Cat>();
        List<Cat> tempCats = new List<Cat>();

        //put 10 cats in
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tempCats.Add(new Cat(i));
            totalCats += 1;
        }

        //add the cats to the final hashset & empty the temp list
        allCats.UnionWith(tempCats);
        tempCats = new List<Cat>();

        //create 10 identical cats
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tempCats.Add(new Cat(i));
            totalCats += 1;
        }

        //join them again
        allCats.UnionWith(tempCats);
        //print the result
        Console.WriteLine("Total cats: " + totalCats);
        foreach (Cat curCat in allCats)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(curCat.CatNumber);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Cat
{
    public int CatNumber { get; set; }
    public Cat(int catNum)
    {
        CatNumber = catNum;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return CatNumber;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Cat)
        {
            return ((Cat)obj).CatNumber == CatNumber;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the example :) I will override both functions in my class and I hope that will solve this.

Answer (score 7):

It *isn't* possible if your type overrides `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` [correctly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx). My guess is that your type hasn't done this properly. (Or your hash set has been created with a custom equality comparer which doesn't do what you want.)

If you believe that's not the case, please post the code :)

But yes, it really *will* prevents duplicates when used normally.